# SVG d3 | can I add inline style dynamically?

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, svg, inline

I need to add an inline style to my SVG dynamically. I have 1000+ SVG charts that I must save as PNGs. These will then be hosted for the end customer (who is not allowed to see the full data behind the charts). When I convert the charts they must keep their formatting.

The SVGs will be added dynamically and I need to add the (same) style declaration to each one. This is ugly but only temporary till I generate the PNGs. I've got inline style / export working manually.

My latest effort is this:

```
addStyle(svg);

function addStyle(svg) {

  var style = svg.append("style")
    .attr("type","text/css")
    .attr("float","left");
}
```

It adds a style /style element but within comments. And it ignores the float: left; whether I add it as .attr() or .style().

**EDIT: added CSS code.** The CSS I need to add is this for the charts:

```
g.axis path {
    fill: none;
    stroke: dimgray;
    stroke-width: 0.5px;

}
g.axis g.tick line {
    stroke: dimgray;
    stroke-width: 1px;
}

g.grid g.tick line {
    stroke: lightgray;
    stroke-width: 0.5px;
}

path.lineF.cons,
path.line.cons {
    stroke: white;
    fill: none;
    stroke-width: 2px;
}


text.import {
    fill: #FF376F; /* pink */
}


rect.import {
    fill: #FF376F; /* pink */
    stroke: white;
    stroke-width: 1px;
    cursor: pointer;

}
text.export {
    fill: #0F86FF;/* blue */

}

rect.export {
    fill: #0F86FF;/* blue */
    stroke: white;
    stroke-width: 1px;
    cursor: pointer;

}

rect.prod2.area,
path.area {
    fill: #0F86FF;
    opacity: 0.8;
}

path.areaF.prod,
rect.prod.area,
path.area.prod {
    fill: black;
    opacity: 0.4;
}

div.chart {
    width: 100%;
}

div.chart svg#svg2 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 20000px;
}

div.chart svg {
    width: 100%;
    height: 15000px;
}

text {
    fill: dimgray;
/*  font-size: 14px; */
    font-size: 90%;
/*  font-size: 1vw; */
}


text.title {
/*  font-size: 20px; */
    font-size: 130%;
    font-size: 1.4vw;
    fill: dimgray;
}


text.titleMain {
    fill: white;
    font-size: 28px;
/*
    font-size: 2.5%;
    font-size: 2.5vw;
*/
}

text.label {
    font-size: 12px;
}

rect.titleRect {
    fill: #1D5185;
}


text.source {
    font-size: 9pt;
    fill: gainsboro;
    font-style: italic;
}

rect.opRate {
    fill: black;
    opacity: 0.6;
}

path.line.opRate {
    stroke: #B7FF0F; /* lime */
    stroke-width: 3px;
    fill: none;
}

text.opRate {
    fill: #B7FF0F;
}


path.arP2 {
    stroke-width: 2px;
    fill: none;
    stroke: black;
}


text.gr0 {
    fill: #0F86FF;
}

text.gr2 {
    fill: #FF376F;
}

text.gr1 {
    fill: #06B04A;

}

path.gr0 {
    stroke: #0F86FF;
    stroke-width: 2px;
    fill: none;
}
path.gr2 {
    stroke: #FF376F;
    stroke-width: 2px;
    fill: none;
}
path.gr1 {
    stroke: #06B04A;
    stroke-width: 2px;
    fill: none;
}

rect.negativeGrowth {
    fill: black;
    opacity: 0.1;
}
```

For the tables, the CSS is this:

```
text.source {
    font-size: 9pt;
    fill: gainsboro;
    font-style: italic;
}



rect.th {
    fill: #0F86FF;
    stroke: white;
    stroke-width: 1px;
}

rect.td {
    stroke: white;
    stroke-width: 1px;
    fill: #C8E0F9;
}

text.tdLabel {

    fill: black;
}

text.th {
    fill: white;
}

text.tableTitle {
    fill: #1D5185;
    font-size: 1.5%;
    font-size: 1.5vw;
}
```

Is it possible to do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: A style tag contains CSS, you'd need to set its textContent to the CSS you need.

Comment: to what element you want to add the style?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
svg.append("style").text(cssText)
```

should do it. Where cssText would be a string containing all your CSS.

that creates a style tag in the DOM and sets its text content to be the CSS you need.

Comment: Thanks - you've saved me loads of time!

Answer (score 0):

Not all css applies to SVG elements. I found a list here : [css style on svg](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/svg-and-css.html#css-attributes). What i would do is put each svg into its own div element (you can easily do that in D3), and then style the div elements. I find styling pure html elements more easy then SVG's, especially when there are a lot.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I don't think it would work. The style element has to be within the svg in order for the SVG to maintain formatting during export (to Illustrator, for example, or to convert into PNG)